# How to open PDF using Javascript in native app

Tags: javascript, java, android

I have an android app that is trying to view a pdf file (in the user native app, i.e. I do not want to render it in my own app). I just want the user to select his preferred pdf app to open my pdf (which I have the relevant path. Is this at all possible using javascript or should it be in java. I tried java but because of difficulties with creating an intent it never worked for me. so I'm hoping to use a workaround using javascript code.

I'm using the following code but it is not working

```
<a id='mylink' href='path to my pdf file' onclick='myfunction'>Click <u>this Link</u></a><br><br>

<script> 

function myfunction() {
window.open('path to my pdf file')
} 
</script>
```

I'm still learning javascript so code above might not be the best.
I'm very open to suggestions on how to improve my code.

Desired outcome:
Is to open a pdf file (referenced in the path-to-file) after asking the user what app he wants to open the pdf with (e.g. adobe, pdfviewer, etc...)

Many thanks indeed for your help in this.